# Powershell Script to output Installed Programs

Tags: powershell, wmi

I'd like to do this using the win32_product wmi class.

I need the script to simply count the number of products installed and also output the time taken to execute the script.

What I have atm doesn't seem to work correctly:

```
    $count = 0
    $products = get-wmiobject -class "Win32_Product"
    foreach ($product in $products) {
          if ($product.InstallState -eq 5) {
                count++
          }
    }
    write-host count
```

Comment: There is a typo in your code: use `$count` instead of `count` in two places.

Answer (score 4):

**Beware!** Using WMI's `Win32_Product` class, which the question and the previous 2 answers do, **is not advised for this purpose.**

In a nutshell: using Win32_Product is ***not*** an innocuous query because it has side effects. Quoting Microsoft, "[It]... initiates a consistency check of packages installed, verifying *and repairing* the install." (emphasis mine)

References:

- [Microsoft Support Reference](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/974524)
- [Use PowerShell to Quickly Find Installed Software (Hey, Scripting Guy! blog)](http://blogs.technet.com/b/heyscriptingguy/archive/2011/11/13/use-powershell-to-quickly-find-installed-software.aspx)
- [Win32_Product WMI Class Replacement](http://csi-windows.com/toolkit/win32product-replacement)
- [Why Win32_Product is Bad News!](http://sdmsoftware.com/group-policy-blog/wmi/why-win32_product-is-bad-news/)

---

**So what is a better (safer) solution?**

Marc Carter, writing the guest column in the *Hey, Scripting Guy!* blog above takes the first volley, providing a custom PowerShell function, back on my system it returned only half as many entries as the Win32_Product invocation. Also, it is a lot of code (3 dozen lines or so). In the comments to his post, however, knutkj offers this much shorter version that does the same thing:

```
Get-ChildItem -Path HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall |
   Get-ItemProperty |
   Sort-Object -Property DisplayName |
   Select-Object -Property DisplayName, DisplayVersion, InstallLocation
```

But it does, as I said, the same thing: not provide a full list. But it is a start.

Later in the comments Nick W reported that there are actually 3 registry paths of interest, though not all may be present on every system. Further, when looking at those 3 paths, one has to do some additional filtering.

Combining both of those, adding in a few more output fields, and making the code safe to run in strict mode, I arrived at this simple solution:

```
function Get-InstalledPrograms()
{
    $regLocations = (
        "HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\", 
        "HKCU:\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\",
        "HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\"
        )

    Get-ChildItem ($regLocations | Where { Test-Path $_ } ) |
        Get-ItemProperty |
        Where {
            ( (Get-Member -InputObject $_ -Name DisplayName) -and $_.DisplayName -ne $Null) -and
            (!(Get-Member -InputObject $_ -Name SystemComponent) -or $_.SystemComponent -ne "1") -and 
            (!(Get-Member -InputObject $_ -Name ParentKeyName) -or $_.ParentKeyName -eq $Null)
            } |
        Sort DisplayName |
        Select DisplayName, DisplayVersion, Publisher, InstallLocation, InstallDate,  URLInfoAbout
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Roman Kuzmin is right about the typo. Correction will solve almost everything.

To make it more powershellish, I would use

```
get-wmiobject -class "Win32_Product" | 
    ? { $_.InstallState -eq 5 } |
    measure-object  | 
    select -exp Count
```

And considering the time, you can wrap it into `measure-command`

```
measure-command { 
  $count = get-wmiobject -class "Win32_Product" | 
              ? { $_.InstallState -eq 5 } | 
              measure-object  |
              select -exp Count
  write-host Count: $count
}
```

Answer (score 2):

A bit late on this but the "more powershellish way":

```
$(Get-WmiObject -Class "Win32_Product" -Filter "InstallState=5").Count
```